# Application stops working when I add two fonts

Tags: android, game-maker, fonts

I created a game that has two fonts.

Being precise, the two fonts are **PRESS_START_2P** with the difference only in size. One of the fonts serves to write the title and the other for all other things.

The problem occurs after building the application (apk). As it is a special font I click on the option "copy to project" for it to be exported to the cell phone.

**Image of the two fonts:**

[image]

A detail is that the program does not recognize the original source directory, so I need to copy the source to the desktop to be able to copy it to the project.

**Image demonstrating the problem:**

[image]

Adding any of the fonts (alone), the game works. The problem happens when I add the second font.

Before posting here, I posted on the official engine forum, but I still haven't gotten any response.

**LINK:**

https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/application-does-not-work-when-i-export-2nd-font.83968/

Comment: Does your application record any logs that might give insights into what happened?

Comment: @DMGregory Nothing different appears in the log. The problem only occurs when running the game on the cell phone.